# Process builder fails running in user context

Tags: process-builder, lead-conversion, process, field-mapping

In my organisation we are Using custom field called **Lead_Source__c** in lead object

In opportunity level we are using standard field called **LeadSource**

Now, i am unable to map it's not showing standard picklist in lead mapping.So,i am mapping to a custom field in opportunity.

And i set up a process in opportunity on creation & field update with updating standard **LeadSource** if custom lead source field have any value.

It's working fine.Now the problem is above process is failing because i have a validation rule on opportunity if any opportunity updates means **NOT(IsNew())** restrict users to modify LeadSource if Lead category is marketing.

As per the community i understood process builder runs on system mode but why validation rule fires in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"System mode" means that Process Builder ignores Field-Level Security (FLS). Processes and most other automations *are always running in the context of a specific user*, and validation rules are applied unless they include some exclusion in their logic, such as not firing for an API, bulk data process, or integration user.

You may wish to modify your validation rule to check whether the LeadSource field is being updated.